# Why merged Fluxes do not interleave concurrently?

Tags: java, merge, project-reactor

I'm new to the Reactor, so I'd like to know, why is merging in this sample code working not as it's subscribed in the documentation. One flux returns odd numbers with a delay of 3 secs and other returns evens with a delay of 2 secs, but when I subscribe, it prints results of the first flux and then of the second one sequentially, but not interspersed. Return is 2, 4, 6, 8, .... 1, 3, 5, 7 etc, while I'm expecting 2, 4, 3, 6, 8, 5, 10, 7 etc. Other words: why don't two sourse fluces run in parallel?
Here's a sample code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Flux.merge(fun1(10), fun2(10)).subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    public static Flux<Integer> fun1(int i) {
        return Flux.range(1, i).map(integer -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return integer * 2;
        });
    }

    public static Flux<Integer> fun2(int i) {
        return Flux.range(1, i).map(integer -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return integer * 2 + 1;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Reactor is concurrency agnostic: by default everything runs on the main thread. In your example this means that `Thread.sleep` is blocking the progress in the main thread that's why the second `Flux` only starts to work after the first. To fix this...

**1. You can use `delay` operator which waits in a non-blocking manner and internally switches to a different thread.**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flux.merge(fun1(10), fun2(10))
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .blockLast(); // block so main thread waits for background threads to finish
}

public static Flux<Integer> fun1(int i) {
    return Flux.range(1, i)
            .concatMap(integer -> Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(2000)).thenReturn(integer * 2));
}

public static Flux<Integer> fun2(int i) {
    return Flux.range(1, i)
            .concatMap(integer -> Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(3000)).thenReturn(integer * 2 + 1));
}
```

**2. You can switch to a different thread manually using a `Scheduler`. In most real-world use cases you'll need this as usually instead of `Thread.sleep` you have for example a blocking database call.**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flux.merge(fun1(10), fun2(10))
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .blockLast(); // block so main thread waits for background threads to finish
}

public static Flux<Integer> fun1(int i) {
    return Flux.range(1, i).map(integer -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return integer * 2;
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}

public static Flux<Integer> fun2(int i) {
    return Flux.range(1, i).map(integer -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return integer * 2 + 1;
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}
```

Note that though, if you are using a reactive non-blocking client (Spring WebClient, R2DBC, etc.) you don't need to specify any `Scheduler` explicitly as these clients take care of that for you just like in case of the `delay` operator.

Useful read in reference docs: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `subscription` happens on the calling thread, which in this case would be `main`. It first enters `fun1(int i)`, and completes the inner `flux`. Then it enters `fun2(int i)`, and finishes the second `flux`. Reactor's pipelines run on the calling thread by default (unlike say `CompletableFuture<T>` that runs on the `fork-join` pool by default). You can see interweaved output in the following code:

```
Flux.merge(fun1(10).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()), fun2(10).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Consider using `Flux.delay` instead of blocking the thread by using `Thread.sleep`.